# Flexbox with horizontal list add a padding-left

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why Flexbox adds a left-padding on a horizontal list even with justify-content: space-between ?

```
 <div class="list-container">
   <ul>
     <li>One</li>
     <li>Two</li>
     <li>Three</li>
     <li>Four</li>
     <li>Five</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

```
.list-container {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}
.list-container ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
}
.list-container li {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: darkorange;
}
```

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/telemacus/vdo9a54c/10/

adding "padding-left: 0" on "ul" fixes the problem.

Comment: It is taking default padding of ul. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34657832/10971575

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove padding use:

```
ul{
  padding: 0;
}
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w783mxaf/