# Horizontally centering a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When using flex for creating a grid of images, how can I horizontally center the grid itself on the page? I still want the images to left-align on each row. I would like it to be dynamic to the number of elements per row.

[**Jsfiddle with what I have so far**](https://jsfiddle.net/p01mx39h/1/show/)

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.gallery-artwork {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery-artwork">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-artwork">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-artwork">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-artwork">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-artwork">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Basically...it's hard...usually requires JS or hidden dummy elements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802202/center-flex-container-but-align-left-flex-items/32811002#32811002

Comment: I'm not sure that a *detailed canonical answer* is really required here. Flexbox is not designed for grids. It's designed to enable more flexible layouts through distribution of empty space. For grids, the W3C is developing the [**CSS Grid Layout Module**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/). Until it gains browser support you can use [**Masonry**](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution will work regardless of the number of elements and width.

https://jsfiddle.net/p01mx39h/14/

```js
function addDummies() {
  imgsPerRow = Math.floor($(".gallery").width() / $(".gallery-artwork").outerWidth(true));
  if (imgsPerRow > 1) {
    missingImages = imgsPerRow - $(".gallery-artwork").length % imgsPerRow;
    while (missingImages > 0) {
      $(".gallery").append("<div class='gallery-artwork-dummy'></div>");
      $(".gallery-artwork-dummy").css('width', $('.gallery-artwork').outerWidth(true));
      missingImages--;
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 addDummies();
});
```

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery-artwork {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery-artwork">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-artwork">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-artwork">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-artwork">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-artwork">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Playing with the width makes the bottom element center instead of go to the left.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by many answer here and on the web, you'll need (at least, for now) dummies elements.
Here's a way to do it easily, without calculation, and in plain JavaScript:

- Add as many dummies as the amount of `.gallery-artwork` elements
- Give these dummies the same style, without any height, nor vertical margins

This method has an advantage: you don't need to do any calculation! You're sure to always have enough dummies (whatever the screen width, the number of elements and their amount per row) to push your elements on the left side of your container.

So here's the code!

```js
var gallery = document.querySelector('.gallery'),
    artworks = gallery.querySelectorAll('.gallery-artwork'),
    dummy = document.createElement('div');
dummy.classList.add('gallery-dummy');

// One element = one dummy
[].forEach.call(artworks, function() {
  gallery.appendChild(dummy.cloneNode());
});
```

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.gallery-artwork {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.gallery-dummy {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery-artwork">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-artwork">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-artwork">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-artwork">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-artwork">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just edited my answer, I missed to use `cloneNode()` function, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

- You can wrap an element around the whole thing and then just center as normal.
- The matter of having the flex items left aligned is as simple as using the default value of `justify-content: flex-start`, *but it doesn't center*. So in order to maintain center-aligned flex-items, we use **`justify-content: center`**.
- It centers perfectly but if the second row has a smaller amount of flex-items, then it'll look like **[this](https://zer00ne.tinytake.com/sf/NDg0OTkzXzI1ODU3NDc)**
- In order to maintain everything being horizontally centered, **and** have a nice left-aligned behavior for the last row, we can add an extra flex-item and give it this: `visibility: hidden`. If the number of flex-items are dynamic, we use the following selector: `.gallery-artwork:last-of-type { visibility: hidden; }`

Here's the [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/ceab4gts/show/)

**CSS**

```
/* The wrap element that surrounds and centers everything */
.exhibition {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
/* justify-content: center is needed for centering of the flex-items */   
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gallery-artwork {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 10px;
}
 /* This is the last of the gallery-artwork (flex-item). 
 Being of the same dimensions as the other flex-items and hidden from site,
fills in the gap of an uneven row of flex-items. */

.gallery-artwork:last-of-type {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="exhibition">
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-artwork">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-artwork">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-artwork">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-artwork">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-artwork">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-artwork">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated CSS:

```
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content:center;
}

.gallery-artwork {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var i = $('.gallery-artwork').length;
    if (i % 2 == 0){
    }else{
        $(".gallery").append("<div class='gallery-artwork'></div>");
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/debraj/p01mx39h/9/

Comment: But then the last image is not left-aligned.

Comment: Are you willing to add some sort of jQuery?

Comment: I would like it to be dynamic to the number of elements per row.

Comment: You can add elements dynamically. It will calculate all divs under `gallery` and if the total number is odd then only append the spacer div.

Comment: This isn't dynamic to the number of elements. Try this one: https://jsfiddle.net/ceab4gts/13/show/

Comment: Still not dynamic, try removing an image

Comment: Yep, that's why removed the comment.

Answer (score -1):

Slightly alter your gallery css:

```
justify-content: center;
```

I used this today, so this is why I popped it in right away. But this [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) page really helped with the flex bits and pieces.

Comment: But then the last row is not left-aligned