# Centering inline blocks

Tags: html, css

So we've got a container, bordered in red, containing a bunch of little inline block elements, bordered in green. It looks to be, more or less, what I want.

[image: Picture here]
**HTML:**

```css
 .featuredBoxContainer {
    max-width: 1780px;
    max-height: 468px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
    .featuredBox {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 200px;
      height: 130px;
      margin: 10px;
      border: 1px solid green;  
    }
```

```html
<div class="featuredBoxContainer">
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div> 
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>
            <div class="featuredBox"></div>             
        </div>
```

My problem becomes more apparent when you shrink the page.

[image]

These elements are all floating left, whereas I'd prefer them to be centered.

Pretty straight forward question. How do I center these within the container?

Comment: Media queries. Here's some background and potential solutions (the answer may appear unrelated until you're half way in): http://stackoverflow.com/a/32811002/3597276

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b80kgtn0/

Comment: I did think of media queries at first, but then again I had kinda hoped there was a more intuitive/easier way to do it.

Thanks for the fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just adding to .featureBoxContainer the following

```
text-align: center;
```

I also suggest you take a look at CSS3 flex

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

```css
.featuredBoxContainer {
  max-width: 1780px;
  max-height: 468px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.featuredBox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 130px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;  
}
```

```html
<div class="featuredBoxContainer">
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div> 
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>             
</div>
```

Comment: I did try to add text-align:center; at first. Problem is, it comes out like this. http://i.imgur.com/CKNJpFi.png

Always more whitespace on the left. Might be there's a way I could fix that.

Comment: This is pretty weird as this behavior is not happening with the snippet. Is there any other HTML/CSS that could be involved?

Comment: @FelixMaxime It is because you have a margin on the left of the first element.

Comment: Figured out why it was doing that! While I was playing around with it, I had tried switching the container/elements into ul/list items. ULs have a natural margin on the left.

Everything works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're only supporting modern browsers, `flexbox` is an option.  On the container, you need a `display:flex;`, a `justify-content:center`, and a `flex-wrap:wrap`.  For broader support, vendor prefixes would be needed.

```css
.featuredBoxContainer {
  max-width: 1780px;
  max-height: 468px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.featuredBox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 130px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;  
}
```

```html
<div class="featuredBoxContainer">
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div> 
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>
  <div class="featuredBox"></div>             
</div>
```