# Center a group of wrapped flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to center a group of wrapped flex items. The HTML looks like this:

```css
main {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 390px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.a1 {
  color: grey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="a1"></div>
    <div class="a1"></div>
    <div class="a1"></div>
    <div class="a1"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/shefwpqr/)

The above looks like this:

[image]

The green boxes are wrapped correctly, but they, as a whole, are not centered in the red area,

[image]

without defining a width on the `.container` because the red block can have any size and I want to fit as many blocks next to each other as possible.

Any suggestions how to center the wrapped green blocks?

UPDATE: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802202/how-to-center-a-flex-container-but-left-align-flex-items) 2 year old post it is not possible. So in my case I have to use javascript to fix this. But maybe I can use [CSS Grid Layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: Yes your update is right, there is no solution with flexbox. But in your duplicate post there is an answer that shows how you can achive it with grid https://stackoverflow.com/a/60870221/2311074 

Note that this only works when your items have a fixed width. That seems to be the case in your case.

Answer (score 33):

Not sure what kind of centering you want do

So a few options:

## Option 1: just center the elements in `.container`

- add `justify-content: center;`  to `.container` instead

```css
main {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 390px;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content:center;
}

.a1 {
  color: grey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="a1"></div>
    <div class="a1"></div>
    <div class="a1"></div>
    <div class="a1"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

## Option 2:  center the  `.container`

- add  some `width` + `margin:auto`  to `.container`

```css
main {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 390px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

.a1 {
  color: grey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="a1"></div>
    <div class="a1"></div>
    <div class="a1"></div>
    <div class="a1"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

## Option 3:  center both from above options

```css
main {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 390px;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
}

.a1 {
  color: grey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="a1"></div>
    <div class="a1"></div>
    <div class="a1"></div>
    <div class="a1"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thnx for the help! Your first option does indeed what I need, except that the 4th block is centered instead of left-aligned.

Comment: you must decide something, you say you want `.container`to have any `width` but then it won't be more than `390px` because you set it in `main`, so using `max-width` with `%`  and `margin` as mentioned in my option #2 and #3 it will work.

Comment: `.container` should not be bigger than its parent. `main` is here `390px` but it could as well be the width of the browser

Comment: So exactly, using `width` in `%` in `.container` will work

Comment: I must say its getting close. Checkout this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j5qom5f7/). The width of the container is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to center the container give a fixed width to the container or make sure that the width of the container has the expected width.

```css
    main {
        background-color: blue;
        width: 390px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .container {
        background-color: red;
        display: inline-flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width:306px;
    }
    
    .a1 {
      color: grey;
      width: 100px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: green;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="a1"></div>
    <div class="a1"></div>
    <div class="a1"></div>
    <div class="a1"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```