# How can I maximize space between divs in same line, but center it if it's the only one?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using `flexbox` to display two containers in a parent container that shrinks.

- When the parent container is large enough such that the two `div`s are side by side, I want them to display as far apart as possible.
- When the parent `div` shrinks and the second `div` wraps to a new line, I want them to display centered horizontally.

Currently I'm using `justify-content: space-between` on the parent container which helps them display as far apart as possible but does nothing to center them when the second `div` wraps.

This is what the current solution using `justify-content: space-between` on the parent `div` looks like:

[image: Current wide]

When the parent div is wide, it displays as intended

[image: Current narrow]

When the parent div is narrow, it wraps but both are left-aligned instead of centered

Ideally, this is what it would look like:

[image: Goal wide]

When the parent div is wide, it maximizes space between them

[image: Goal narrow]

When the parent div is narrow, it centers both divs horizontally

I've tried all sorts of CSS tricks but a key constraint of this problem is that it must be done with pure CSS, no outside frameworks like React. I found [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208025/center-a-group-of-wrapped-flex-items) from 6 years ago that's talking about a similar thing and how it can't be done in `flexbox` but can be done with `grid` assuming the two child `div`s are fixed width, in my case however, the children's `width`s are not fixed.

Here's an easy-to-read version of my code:

```css
    #main {
        font-size: 50px;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    #parent {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    #child1 {
        background: #FFFFD0;
    }

    #child2 {
        background: #FFD0FF;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="main">
        <div id="parent">
            <div id="child1">
                Div #1
            </div>
            <div id="child2">
                Div #2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**An important note**: I'm only able to specify properties directly on the HTML objects. I don't have a CSS file to create classes, which is why in the code snippet I'm using IDs, since that's essentially the limit of what I'm able to do. I'm building an HTML string to pass from the backend to the frontend to display there. I know this isn't optimal or even good practice but it's what the technical constraints of the problem are.

Comment: Is there a possibility for you to share the css code you have so far?

Comment: Please see [ask]. You're required to show some code.

Comment: Apologies, updated with code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

So according to the images you've posted I'm assuming you are using a `@media` query in your css to get the children to wrap to a new line on smaller screens. If so, try the following:

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.child {
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.child:nth-child(odd) {
  background: lightblue;
}

.child:nth-child(even) {
  background: pink;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .parent {
    width: fit-content;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  .child {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child child1">
      DIV 1
    </div>
    <div class="child child2">
      Hell yeah! I'm the meanest...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm actually using `flex-wrap: wrap`, and sorry but I forgot a crucial detail in the original post - I'm only able to use the equivalent of IDs in the CSS since I'm manually constructing the HTML string, so each element needs its properties specified individually. Thank you for the answer though!

Comment: @arkostin01 You can easily replace the `class` with `id`, but either way you prefer to stack them using `flex-wrap` only right? You can try changing `justify-content: space-between` to `justify-content: space-around`, but it won't get the EXACT output you are looking for on larger screens.

Comment: Yep, that combined with `column-gap` was the closest solution I could find, and unfortunately it didn't cut it :( Thank you anyway!