# Dynamic number of columns, all centered, left-justified internally

Tags: css

I have a number of tiles, all the same, static width and height inside some container. The width of the container is dynamic. The number of tiles is dynamic. I need the tiles to "wrap" such that as many as possible fit on each row but a new row is created when the number of tiles fills up the width of the container. A full row of tiles should be centered. A row of tiles that is not full should be left aligned with a full row (or positioned as if it was full and centered). See the diagram below.

[image: Diagram 1]

In this diagram, the green represents the container, the black represents the tiles.

I can get close by making the tiles `inline-block` and using `text-align: center` on the container. However, that comes out like the following instead:

[image: Diagram 2]

Here's a code sample. I am able to make necessary changes to the HTML.

```css
.container {
  border: 5px solid #0f0;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tile {
  margin: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show us your code? Flexbox comes to mind here, but the last row won't be properly aligned if it lacks more than 2 elements.

Comment: @powerbuoy I added a code snippet.

Comment: [**How to center a flex container but left-align flex items**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32802202/3597276)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### TL;DR

There is a way to do it with the [CSS Grid Layout](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/). One has to put the following properties to the parent element, which is the `.container` element in this scenario:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 60px);
grid-gap: 10px;
justify-content: center;
```

---

#### Some explanation and details

I've tried a lot to make this work, but in the end I was only successful with the CSS Grid Layout which I used for the first time here. I bet there are more readers that aren't very familiar with the above properties so I will add one or two lines of explanation for each.

```
display: grid;
```

There's not much to say about this, apart from the limitations in [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid).

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 60px);
```

> The [grid-template-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) CSS property defines the line names and track sizing functions of the grid columns.

This property is a bit more complicated as there are many different options for its value. Here we use the [repeat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat) function which requires the number of columns as first argument and the width of each column cell as second argument. Fortunately, it's possible to define a variable column number by using `auto-fill`. The width of `60px` is the width of the `.tile` (50px for the width and 10px for the border).

```
grid-gap: 10px;
```

> The [grid-gap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-gap) CSS property is a shorthand property for grid-row-gap and grid-column-gap specifying the gutters between grid rows and columns.

To define different gap widths for columns and rows you can use `grid-gap: 5px 10px;` where the first value is for the row-gap. I randomly selected `10px` for this example.

```
justify-content: center;
```

Finally let's tell the browser to center the content of our container (*the grid*) if there is space around. This property is not related to the CSS Grid Layout. It is usually used in flexbox scenarios but works like a charm here as well.

---

#### Demo

I added the described four properties to the `.container` and removed the margin as well as the width from the `.tile`. Solution tested in Firefox 52 and Chrome 57.

```css
.container {
  border: 5px solid #0f0;
  width: 250px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 60px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tile {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

#### Nice to know

In the FF developer console (F12) there is a built-in grid highlighter that allows easy debugging of the defined grid:

[image: Built-in grid highlighter in the FF developer console]

Comment: +1 for tackling the problem with CSS Grid Layout. And thanks for the explanations. (BTW, for anybody reading this, CSS Grid Layout is now fully supported by Chrome and FF).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use flexbox, but if the last row doesn't have enough elements you'll have a similar issue as with inline-block.

You can use :before and :after to fill out the last row, but if more than 2 elements are missing from the last row it won't help entirely.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div > * {
  margin: 1rem;
}

div::before,
div::after {
  background: red; /* For demo only */
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 1rem;
  order: 99999999;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
</div>
```

Edit: Looking at my own example I realise this doesn't solve your problem. I'll delete this post unless it helps you somehow anyway.

Edit2: You may actually have to resolve to adding some empty divs using JS to fill out the void. That should work though I'd definitely consider it an ugly hack.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Adding empty divs would be acceptable, though of course hacky. I'll leave the question open for a couple days to see if anyone else has a better suggestion (it would be nice if there was a way to do this with just CSS), but if nothing comes I'll accept yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below,

```css
.container {
  border: 5px solid #0f0;
  width: 250px;
}

.tile {
  margin: 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

All I did is removed the `text-align` from `.container` class and moved it to `.tile` class. Added a margin to space the elements. You can adjust the `5px 10px` based on your needs. Am able to match the output to yours. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this matches my needs. Please read my detailed description of what I'm trying to accomplish: Variable width container, variable number of tiles per row, dynamically centered