# Can I add a border between flex iItems on the same line?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to add a border between flex items on the same line. I have `flex-wrap: wrap;` set, so I need a way to detect if the flex item is in a row with another flex item some how or if its in its own row when the page renders (it could be either).

If it is occupying a row with another flex item, that is the case where I would add the divider, otherwise, no divider. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420635/14956277):

> In CSS, once the browser renders the page on the initial cascade, it doesn't reflow the document when an element wraps. As a result, parent elements don't know when their children wrap.
>
> That's why containers don't shrink-to-fit their content after wrapping.
>
> That's why you need media queries or JavaScript.

Knowing that, here's an example of using JavaScript to insert your dividers when necessary.

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");

var firstItemInCurrentRow = items[0];
items.forEach(item => {

  // Check if the current item is at the same
  // height as the first item in the current row.
  if (item.offsetTop === firstItemInCurrentRow.offsetTop) {

    // Don't apply the style to the first item
    // in the current row.
    if (item !== firstItemInCurrentRow) {

      // Add the divider.
      item.style.borderLeft = "1px solid black";
      item.style.paddingLeft = "5px";
    }
  }
  else {
    // This item was lower, it must be
    // the first in a new row.
    firstItemInCurrentRow = item;
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  flex-basis: 200px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no straightforward way to do this. You have two options:

1. if you can expect the count of items in each row for different screen sizes, you can use `@media` queries and set the border based on the screen size, ex: if it's expected that there will be **5** items on each row except the last row on `(min-width: 1024px)`,
   then you can have:

   ```css
   .item {
       border-right: 1px solid red;
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
       .item:nth-child(5n), .item:last-child {
           border-right: none;
       }
   }
   ```
2. if your rows will be more dynamic and there's no expected count, you'll need to use JavaScript. for example, loop for items and check their `offsetTop`, for every item with the same value add border-left, except the first one, then do the same with the next value (which means that you are on a different row), and so on!

Answer (score 0):

The only single item would be the last one.

So you could use borders for all those items and remove it on on the first and last.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 220px;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: aliceblue;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
}

.flex-item:first-child, .flex-item:last-child {
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="flex-item">1</div>
    <div class="flex-item">2</div>
    <div class="flex-item">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This only seems to work if you know, beforehand, that you will have exactly one item on the last row. With a row longer than two items (which is very likely), this wouldn't work.