# How to change flexbox wrap?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a responsive flexbox box with dynamically rendered cards (from 1-10 cards rendered each api call) in my application. It Almost does exactly what i want it to do except the way it wraps.

Let's say i rendered 10 cards, if i resize screen so it turns into e.g. 4-4-2 the last 2 cards are centered, i want it to wrap so the last 2 cards start from the left and with equal spacing like the cards above. How can you do that?

EDIT to eloborate further: let's say i resize even further into 1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 , the cards should appear centered, i still need the centering, but i want the last 2 cards to wrap from the left side if it turns into 4-4-2 or 3-3-2 etc.

https://codepen.io/hyrosian/pen/EXKZJz

```css
.card {
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #d4d4d5, 0 0 0 1px #d4d4d5;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;

}

.recipe-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="recipe-grid">
    
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
      <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
      <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
      <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
      <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
      <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
      <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
      <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
      <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
      <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
      <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
      <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
      <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
      <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
      <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
      <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
      <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
      <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
      <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
      <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
      <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
    </div>
    
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center a flex container but left-align flex items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802202/how-to-center-a-flex-container-but-left-align-flex-items)

Comment: `.card:last-child {
  margin-right:auto;
}` is this what you try to do ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXOMVZ

Comment: that breaks if it turns into 2-2-2-2-2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If to use Flexbox, and without script, you could create *ghost* elements, so they fill out the space on the last line.

So for a possible column length of 4, you need 3 *ghost* element and so on.

It is also possible to use the pseudo elements, which will decrease the needed *ghost*'s by 2.

```css
.card {
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #d4d4d5, 0 0 0 1px #d4d4d5;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
.card:empty {
    width: 300px;
    box-shadow: none;
    margin: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;

}

.recipe-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="recipe-grid">
    
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
      <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
      <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
      <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
      <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
      <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
      <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
      <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
      <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
      <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
      <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
      <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
      <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
      <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
      <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
      <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
      <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
      <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
      <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
      <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
      <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
    </div>
    

    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Updated

Since you use `justify-content: space-around`, you could also do like this, where you add an extra wrapper around the `card`, center it and then, with media queries, make the wrappers fill the line based on the amount of items per row.

*Note, since one can't use `CSS calc` in the media query, the values are based on `1rem` equals `16px`, so the first is calculated like this: `300px + (2rem * 2) = 728px` and so on. So if your browsers's default font size on the* *`root`* *element is anything but `16px`, you either set it to that, or recalculate the query values*

```css
.card {
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #d4d4d5, 0 0 0 1px #d4d4d5;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.recipe-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.recipe-grid .card-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width:  728px) { .recipe-grid .card-wrapper { width: 50%;     } }
@media (min-width: 1092px) { .recipe-grid .card-wrapper { width: 33.333%; } }
@media (min-width: 1456px) { .recipe-grid .card-wrapper { width: 25%;     } }
@media (min-width: 1820px) { .recipe-grid .card-wrapper { width: 20%;     } }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="recipe-grid">
    
    <div class="card-wrapper">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
        <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
        <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
      </div>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card-wrapper">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
        <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
        <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
      </div>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card-wrapper">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
        <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
        <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
      </div>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card-wrapper">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
        <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
        <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
      </div>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card-wrapper">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
        <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
        <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
      </div>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card-wrapper">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
        <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
        <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
      </div>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card-wrapper">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
        <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
        <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
      </div>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card-wrapper">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
        <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
        <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
      </div>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card-wrapper">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
        <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
        <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
      </div>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card-wrapper">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
        <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
        <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
      </div>
    </div>
     
    <div class="card-wrapper">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://www.edamam.com/web-img/40b/40bfe88c879112dfc1786938c6c36832.jpg">
        <h3> Egg beef sandwich </h3>
        <p> 604 kcal - totally vegan </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Finally, I also want to mention these posts, [how-to-center-a-flex-container-but-left-align-flex-items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802202/how-to-center-a-flex-container-but-left-align-flex-items) and [can-i-change-the-justify-content-value-depending-on-the-number-of-elements-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46084356/can-i-change-the-justify-content-value-depending-on-the-number-of-elements-in/46088753#46088753) (which might can be considered a duplicate to this), as it has a great explanation how Flexbox works when it comes to its ability to both wrap and center items, and some more solutions than the one's I gave.

Comment: checking this out, would probably need a counter for amount of rendered cards in react.

Comment: @Hyrule If you know there will be no more than 7 columns, just create 6 _ghost_ elements, ... and because it doesn't matter if there are to many as they only take up space horizontally, it will work on 6,5,4,3,2 columns as well

Answer (score -1):

Change your CSS as follows:

```
.recipe-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start
}
```

Add margin to the cards if you need to.

Comment: this removes the centering of the cards if i resize and Everything starts from the left instead the last 2 cards.

Comment: That does not solve the problem of the OP which is about centering the container horizontally.