# How can I line up my lists/pargraph so they match the image in html?

Tags: html, css

So I am make a portfolio for myself and am new to html and css. But I am having trouble trying to bring what I designed in Photoshop to life. This is what I have [image]

and this what I want [image]

I am having trouble with the grid system, I used http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/calculator/ to get my grids. But if you can provide a better grid system that would be awesome. Another issue is trying to line up name: Date: and e.g.. so they are lined up with the image.

```
Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/d31z1z4s/
```

Comment: Tell me about the red box that says "Test Hello the Next." Do you not know how to add a new row below the top row, or is that actually supposed to be below the top-right box?

Comment: @cjl750 I was testing to see if I should use the <p> element to add things like name, date, language used and other stuff. At first I used the list element but I couldn't get the text to be positioned how I wanted them.

Comment: Gotcha. I will not touch that in my answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is basically that your images are fixed width but your containers are flexible. That presents a problem when the images get to be bigger than the containers.

The solution is to take the widths and heights out of the HTML and include it in the CSS. Instead of this:

```
<img src="http://swords.cc/lotzine/250x250.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="250" height="250">
```

Do this:

```
<img src="http://swords.cc/lotzine/250x250.gif" alt="Smiley face">

.col img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Now, whatever size your containers are, your images will just fill that space.

If you want to make sure the images don't go above a certain size, you can use `max-width` on them. For example:

```
.col img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
}
```

Note that adding

```
.col {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

will help you with your sizes, so that your containers are always truly the size you want them to be, and not bigger than you think because of the border. Adding `box-sizing: border-box` will include the border in the size.

---

Since you want the images to not get too big, you need to account for what happens when they wrap to a new line. One way to do this is to center the images within their container, and then center the containers within each other. Then, using media queries, ensure the containers are not too wide when the images collapse to two columns and one column, so things still appear correctly centered.

Here's a snippet where I stripped out extraneous stuff to demonstrate this effect (try running it at full size and resizing the browser window). Compare styles with your own to see what all I stripped out; some of your styles were unnecessary because they were just repeating defaults.

```css
/* general styles */
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.portfolio-col {
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto; /* center the container for the rows */
}
.portfolio-col h2 {
  text-decoration: overline underline;
  text-decoration-color: #fff;
}
.col li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.group:after {
  clear: both; /* these styles are called a clearfix (look it up) */
}

/* each row */
.row {
  clear: both;
  padding: 0px;
}
.col {
  float: left;
  margin: 1% 3.3%; /* equally space our boxes, instead of different left and right margins; specific numbers you can adjust */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.col ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px; /* same width and max-width as our images */
}
.col img {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) { /* slightly before our images would collapse to two columns */
  /* keep our images centered when they go to two columns */
  .portfolio-col {
    max-width: calc(500px + 12%); /* width of two images + 4x 3% margins */
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 740px) { /* slightly before our images would collase to one column */
  .portfolio-col {
    max-width: calc(250px + 6%); /* width of one image + its left and right margins */
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="port-folio" id="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="portfolio-col">
      <h2>MY PROJECTS</h2>
      <div class="row group">
        <div class="col span_1_of_3">
          <img src="http://swords.cc/lotzine/250x250.gif" alt="Smiley face">
          <ul class="project-info">
            <li>Name: Rock</li>
            <li>Created By: Doe</li>
            <li>Date: June 2017</li>
            <li>Language: Java</li>
            <li><a href="">More Info</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col span_1_of_3">
          <img src="http://swords.cc/lotzine/250x250.gif" alt="Smiley face">
          <ul class="project-info">
            <li>Name: Player</li>
            <li>Created By: Doe</li>
            <li>Date: August 2017</li>
            <li>Language: Java</li>
            <li><a href="">More Info</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col span_1_of_3">
          <img src="http://swords.cc/lotzine/250x250.gif" alt="Smiley face">
          <ul class="project-info">
            <li>Name: Game</li>
            <li>Created By: Doe</li>
            <li>Date: August 2017</li>
            <li>Language: Game Maker Language (GML)</li>
            <li><a href="">More Info</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[**Here's a Fiddle of that**](https://jsfiddle.net/7xsjwpb5/).

That works pretty good, but you may notice that the `h2` is not quite centered at larger screens. We can fix that a number of ways, such as by adjusting the left margin of `.row .col:first-of-type` to be more than `3.3%` in a media query, or adjust the left margin of the header in a media query, or maybe by just moving the header outside of its wrapper and into a new one that's always centered.

---

Another approach is **[flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**. This takes even less code to get better centering, although if you want to left-align the last item when it wraps to a new row, that'd take additional styles (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482120/how-to-change-flexbox-wrap) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802202/how-to-center-a-flex-container-but-left-align-flex-items)).

Compare the HTML in this one with your HTML: I deleted the `.row` elements, and moved the `h2`.

```css
/* general styles */

body {
  margin: 0;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: overline underline;
  text-decoration-color: #fff;
}
.col li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.group:after {
  clear: both;
  /* these styles are called a clearfix (look it up) */
}


/* grid layout with flexbox */
.portfolio-col {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.col {
  margin: 1% 3.3%;
  /* equally space our boxes, instead of different left and right margins; specific numbers you can adjust */
  flex-shrink: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.col ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  /* same width and max-width as our images */
}
.col img {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<section class="port-folio" id="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>MY PROJECTS</h2>
    <div class="portfolio-col">
      <div class="col span_1_of_3">
        <img src="http://swords.cc/lotzine/250x250.gif" alt="Smiley face">
        <ul class="project-info">
          <li>Name: Rock</li>
          <li>Created By: Doe</li>
          <li>Date: June 2017</li>
          <li>Language: Java</li>
          <li><a href="">More Info</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col span_1_of_3">
        <img src="http://swords.cc/lotzine/250x250.gif" alt="Smiley face">
        <ul class="project-info">
          <li>Name: Player</li>
          <li>Created By: Doe</li>
          <li>Date: August 2017</li>
          <li>Language: Java</li>
          <li><a href="">More Info</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col span_1_of_3">
        <img src="http://swords.cc/lotzine/250x250.gif" alt="Smiley face">
        <ul class="project-info">
          <li>Name: Game</li>
          <li>Created By: Doe</li>
          <li>Date: August 2017</li>
          <li>Language: Game Maker Language (GML)</li>
          <li><a href="">More Info</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**[Here's a fiddle of that](https://jsfiddle.net/7xsjwpb5/1/)**.

---

To answer your question about what to do with the captions, there are a few options. The examples above use `ul` and `li` as you did, which is fine.

You could also use a single `p` for each one with `br` tags between each line, or you could even wrap each line in a `span` and use `display: block` (since spans are `display: inline` by default). You could also put each line in its own `div` (and optionally wrap them all in a `div` to group them together).

Comment: But the images aren't starting at 250 x 250, is there a way to fix that but still have it responsive? Also do you think I should use list's to store my project info or paragraphs? Last thing can you add comments so I have something to look at in the future.

Comment: @Cmi yes, we can adjust the sizes and make it responsive, but I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to do. What do you mean "aren't starting at 250px"? Do we want to ensure the images are at least that wide and scale them up if necessary? Or are your actual images different dimensions? Another option is to not have the images be flexible width and just make the layout adjust to two and then one column when necessary.

Comment: @Cmi Also, I would probably not use lists for your captions, but that's not to say you couldn't. Your captions are off-center now because of the default left padding on the `ul`, but if you just set that to zero, it'll be fine. There's a few different other options I could show you. And I'd be happy to insert some comments, sure.

Comment: By size I meant have it start being 250x250 because the images look a little big. For the captions I did something like https://jsfiddle.net/8honeobn/ and let me know when you added the comments.

Comment: @Cmi I have substantially revised the answer. Hopefully that is helpful for you. There's comments in the snippets and fiddles.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help, I really appreciate you taking the time to help. I will be for sure checking out css-tricks.com as I see there is a lot on there that I can learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
<section class="port-folio" id="portfolio">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="portfolio-col">
                    <h2>MY PROJECTS</h2>
                    <div class="row group">
                    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                        <img src="http://swords.cc/lotzine/250x250.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="250" height="250">
                        <ul class="project-info">
                            <li>Name: Rock</li>
                            <li>Created By: Doe</li>
                            <li>Date: June 2017</li>
                            <li>Language: Java</li>
                            <li><a href="">More Info</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                        <img src="http://swords.cc/lotzine/250x250.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="250" height="250">
                        <ul class="project-info">
                            <li>Name: Player</li>
                            <li>Created By: Doe</li>
                            <li>Date: August 2017</li>
                            <li>Language: Java</li>
                            <li><a href="">More Info</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                        <img src="http://swords.cc/lotzine/250x250.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="250" height="250">
                        <ul class="project-info">
                            <li>Name: Game</li>
                            <br>
                            <li>Created By: Doe</li>
                            <li>Date: August 2017</li>
                            <li>Language: Game Maker Language (GML)</li>
                            <li><a href="">More Info</a></li>


                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>


          <div class="row group">
                    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                        <img src="http://swords.cc/lotzine/250x250.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="250" height="250">
                        <ul class="project-info">
                            <li>Name: Rock</li>
                            <li>Created By: Doe</li>
                            <li>Date: June 2017</li>
                            <li>Language: Java</li>
                            <li><a href="">More Info</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                        <img src="http://swords.cc/lotzine/250x250.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="250" height="250">
                        <ul class="project-info">
                            <li>Name: Player</li>
                            <li>Created By: Doe</li>
                            <li>Date: August 2017</li>
                            <li>Language: Java</li>
                            <li><a href="">More Info</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                        <img src="http://swords.cc/lotzine/250x250.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="250" height="250">
                        <ul class="project-info">
                            <li>Name: Game</li>
                            <br>
                            <li>Created By: Doe</li>
                            <li>Date: August 2017</li>
                            <li>Language: Game Maker Language (GML)</li>
                            <li><a href="">More Info</a></li>


                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>


</div>
</section>
```

Also, if you want creative design 
Pls. do check

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/carousel-extended