# css centralize boxes without justify to center

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

[image: Edit 983oq88yro]

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const styles = {
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
};

const item = {
  width: '26%',
}

const container = {
   marginLeft: 'auto',  
   marginRight: 'auto',
   width: '100%',
}

const App = () => (
  <div style={container}>
    <div style={styles}>
      <div style={item}>test1</div>
      <div style={item}>test2</div>
      <div style={item}>test3</div>
      <div style={item}>test4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Is there a way to make `test4` appear under `test1`, but still keep the items centralised to the parent container?

Changing `justifyContent` to `flex-start` would cause the entire flexbox to align to the left of the parent.

Comment: In the dupe link, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46088753/2827823) show how to left align items and keep the parent centered using Flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

1. your items should have `flex: 1 1 33%` as a rule, this is a shortcut for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`;
2. you have to select the fourth item and set `flex-basis: 100%`;
3. create children inside the flexbox items and then centralise them.

In my experience you should **never** have a component as a direct children of a flexbox; you should **always** use the items as containers for your components.

Keep in mind that flexbox is not well supported by old browsers (IE10) and most of IE versions have problem with flexbox. Use it carefully.

Comment: the actual use case has a fixed width rather than percentage, so i'd have to detect the window width, calculate the paddings etc to get the number of elements in last row.

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve, would be nice having an example. The container of the flexbox could be fixed and flex items could be fixed as well if needed. Anyway flexbox should be always 100%, then it's the parent which decides the width of it's children (in this case the flexbox container would be the children of a general container).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify width on the `inner` container and add `margin: 0 auto` to center it.

Something like that

```
const styles = {
  display: 'flex',
  width: '70%',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
  marginLeft: 'auto',
  marginRight: 'auto',
};
```

[image: Edit qk1wprnxxw]

Comment: this would constraint the container to 70% width, not desirable