# Display in Grid

Tags: html, css, react-native, flexbox

I am trying to format my items into a grid view using ReactNative. However, when the items count is odd, it will show as per the picture attached. Anyway can format the third item to align left?

ListView css

```
grid: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        flex: 1,
    },
```

[image]

Comment: Basically, not natively with flexbox. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802202/how-to-center-a-flex-container-but-left-align-flex-items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change justifyContent property to be 'flex-start'

Comment: looks great, but if the device has smaller width, then each row will have only one item and aligned to left? anyway can make align to center for that case?

Comment: I think that goes against the question. But again, if the image view is 
 of constant width you can get device width and with simple comparison you can dynamically set the css as 'center' or 'flex-start'.

Comment: @jokerday and Ashish: That's what media query's is for...

Comment: Display Items in grid using flatlist. It is the best option