# center multiple panels with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I currently have a set of panels that while in full screen a centered correctly, when they are at a small resolution, they are not.
Basically I have a container with around 7 panels in it:

```
<div class"container">
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
```

I have created a code pen to show what it looks like in full screen: 
https://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/XemvyW?editors=0100

and in a small resolution (i.e. mobile) it looks like this:
https://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/eGJOJN?editors=0100

I have made the background colour pink on the second codepen. I would like the items centering in the second pen without affecting the way it looks in a large resultion.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Related if not Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802202/how-to-center-a-flex-container-but-left-align-flex-items

Comment: It's not a duplicate, their layout they require is not the same as mine

Comment: Hence I used "Related". This issues are essentially the same though.

Comment: they are not though, he can solve his using flexbox. I can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed this:

https://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/OxMyPL?editors=0100#0

All I did was get rid of the flexbox on the container of the panels and updated the **persona-panels** to use margins with **calc** like this:

```
.persona-panels {
    > div {
        .panel {
            vertical-align: top;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 7.5px calc((100% - #{$persona-panel-width}) / 2);

            @include large-width {
                margin: 7.5px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a div with class ng-scope inside the flex-container. It blocks the code from being effective/working. Remove that from the html or make that your flex container. This is what your code actually looks like:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="ng-scope DELETE THIS DIV">
      <div class="panel"></div>
      <div class="panel"></div>
      <div class="panel"></div>
      <div class="panel"></div>
      <div class="panel"></div>
      <div class="panel"></div>
      <div class="panel"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And in the css remove the `inline-block` from line 222 and it will center. Then add `flex-flow: row wrap` to .persona-panels.

Answer (score -1):

Changing the `display` property on the panels is messing it up.

Flexbox's `display` property works differently in that it changes the children too, children then become flex items.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802202/how-to-center-a-flex-container-but-left-align-flex-items) answer, though, it's more practical to just use `inline-block`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove property this property from .panel. then it will work fine

`display-inline-block`

Comment: no it won't because it will just force them all into 1 column

Comment: This solution is not going to work. It destroys the layout for the full screen. Secondly, it would not be `display-inline-block`, but `display: inline-block`.

Comment: The original poster has given links to his code in his original question.