# Center a list of elements while and also have them justified left

Tags: html, css, layout

**Scenario :**

- I have a list of inline-block elements that I'm able to center.
- But when the number of elements don't fit on a line, 
   **Todo :** I would like
  them to be justified to the left.
- I've been messing with flex boxes
  and other things, but I seem to only be able to do one at a time
  (center the entire element or justify the elements left).

Anyone know
   how to accomplish this?

Below is the jsfiddle I've been messing around with, as well as some images that are hopefully helpful.

**What I have:**
[image: what I have]

**What I want:**
[image: what I want]

https://jsfiddle.net/bonbonlemon/bu1y93Ls/52/

**Code:**

**jsx:**

```
<div>
  <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Increase!</button>
  <div id="items-box">
    { items.map((item, idx) => (
      <div className="item-box" key={idx}>{item}</div>
    ))}
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#items-box {
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item-box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 110px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  outline: thin solid black;
}
```

Comment: I think *[that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32811002/3986258)* might help you out!

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try to use flexbox:

https://jsfiddle.net/hapu8ny2/

```
html,
body {
   min-height: 100%;
}

#items-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.item-box {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 110px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  outline: thin solid black;
}
```

**Note**: see i use `min-height` and `min-width` instead

Comment: Not quite. I would like to keep the entire items-box centered.

Comment: And? its totally centered to `#items-box` i edit the fiddle to more seeing result