# How to properly center and align flex items in Tailwind CSS when using justify-start and items-center?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I use Tailwind CSS to style cards within a flex container. Initially, I centered the cards horizontally and vertically using `items-center` and `justify-center`. However, I encountered an issue where when there are only a few cards, they leave ample space between them. To address this, I tried using `justify-start`, which resolved the spacing problem, but it caused the cards not to be centered correctly within the container.

My current setup:

```
<main className="max-w-[1200px] mx-auto my-20 flex flex-wrap items-center justify-start gap-5">
  {series &&
    series.map(
      (serie) =>
        serie.backdrop_path &&
        serie.overview &&
        !("success" in serie) && (
          <div
            className="w-[170px] max-w-sm lg:w-[220px] rounded text-slate-200 p-2 flex-shrink-0"
            key={serie.id}
          >
            <DataCard dataType={serie} />
          </div>
        )
    )}
</main>
```

And here is the current result:

[image]

What I want it to be:

[image]

I would like to know how I can maintain the alignment of the cards to the start of the container while ensuring they are centered horizontally within it. Any suggestions or insights on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using `flex-wrap`

Comment: Try justify-content: center;

Answer (score 0):

Using `flex-wrap` would help you out

Example:

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap w-full items-center justify-center gap-4">
  <div class="flex h-auto w-[170px] max-w-sm flex-shrink-0 items-start justify-center rounded p-2 text-slate-200 lg:w-[220px]">
    <div class="flex h-[12rem] w-[10rem] items-center justify-center bg-yellow-100"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex h-auto w-[170px] max-w-sm flex-shrink-0 items-start justify-center rounded p-2 text-slate-200 lg:w-[220px]">
    <div class="flex h-[12rem] w-[10rem] items-center justify-center bg-red-100"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex h-auto w-[170px] max-w-sm flex-shrink-0 items-start justify-center rounded p-2 text-slate-200 lg:w-[220px]">
    <div class="flex h-[12rem] w-[10rem] items-center justify-center bg-green-100"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex h-auto w-[170px] max-w-sm flex-shrink-0 items-start justify-center rounded p-2 text-slate-200 lg:w-[220px]">
    <div class="flex h-[12rem] w-[10rem] items-center justify-center bg-yellow-100"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex h-auto w-[170px] max-w-sm flex-shrink-0 items-start justify-center rounded p-2 text-slate-200 lg:w-[220px]">
    <div class="flex h-[12rem] w-[10rem] items-center justify-center bg-red-100"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Here I've used `flex-wrap` in the parent. You can use the same method to fix your problem.

Comment: i already had this but my problem is i want them to not start from the center like this but from the left but when i do that as i shown in screenshot the space around the main container got pushed to the right

Comment: for that I think you would need separate rows, you can do so by making an array that increments its items and accordingly calculates the number of rows

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve that with just flex box, you have to give max-width to container, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60870221/23468226) you can learn more.
By the way I recommends you to use grid layout in this case:

```html
<main className="mx-auto my-20 grid w-fit grid-cols-2 gap-5 bg-red-400 sm:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-4 lg:grid-cols-5">
  // content 
</main>
```

Comment: I already use max width with max-w-[] How to use grid in this case using tailwindcss ?